How can I train the tesseract in Python?
I'm having a lot of difficulties, I have an image of several things written, when he reads it he can't identify many things, but I know the position of each item in the image, I've already made a .box with everything correct. I'm not able to do the tests and not create a model to use.
I can't understand how to do all this.
Can anyone explain to me what I should do to train tesseract, for example I want to use the model it already has by default and train it's
I've already tried using gpt, I've read their tutorial, but I can't understand what's happening so I can't generate the trained model
